# Use App Maker User Picker Return a List of Email Address

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a question regarding to user picker in app maker. I have a sever script which will use for adding members into a team drive. I want to use the user picker widget to select member, then send to sever script.

I have followed the examples of Training Hub and Documents Approval, which create a datasources to capture the data. I am not really into that approach. (But if this is the only way, I can compromise)

Is it possible that user picker can directly input a list of email in UI? 
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no Multi User Picker widget at this time and I think you found okish samples for its custom implementation. Feel free to file a feature request to App Maker team: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192783&template=833411

Comment: Thanks @PavelShkleinik! You are always very helpful! I figure it probably the case. I will try something else, and hoping App Maker would add that feature soon.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm keeping my fingers crossed too ;)